# Sesame SeRQL does not provide update/insert option?

Tags: ontology, sesame

I'm trying to use Sesame repository to store my ontology. I wanted to write JAVA code to load this ontology or just run queries on it so as to add new individuals, properties etc. But it seems that SeRQL does not provide update operations. Is there some API that will allow me to do that? I was able to do the same using the OWLAPI, but it could load the ontology from a file and not from the sesame repository.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SeRQL doesn't support update operations. SPARQL does in its 1.1 version, but I believe that Sesame doesn't yet support SPARQL 1.1. The way to update a Sesame repository is through the [SAIL API](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/system/ch05.html). Start a transaction to add and remove individual statements.

Comment: This is now somewhat out of date. Sesame does support SPARQL 1.1, including updates.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanted to point out that Sesame's main access API is actually the [Repository API](http://www.openrdf.org/doc/sesame2/users/ch08.html). It's much easier to use than the sail (which is not really intended for direct access, but is a system-internal API for wrapping different storage and reasoning backends).